# Como simular escrita em input pelo Javascript (sem Jquery)

Tags: javascript, eventos, javascript-eventos, teclado

Preciso simular um input como se alguem estivese digitando isto inclui a chamada dos eventos Keyup, KeyDown, Keypress, Change etc...
Apenas javascript mesmo sem JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente, fiz um exemplo bem simples que simula a digitação de uma palavra em um `input`.

Caso seja uma frase ou algo mais complexo, peço que deixe mais claro por gentileza em sua pergunta ou me informe nos comentários se não é bem isso que você quer.

Se não entendi corretamente me informe que deleto a resposta.

**EDIT:** Adicionado eventos de keyup, keypress e keydown na digitação desta simulação. Para melhor visualização dos eventos, dexei comentado o keypress e o keydown.

Segue abaixo:

```js
function simulate() {
  var word = "Otorrinolaringologista";
  var wordsplit = word.split("");
  var i = 0;
  var time = setInterval(function() {    
    if (!wordsplit[i]) {
      clearInterval(time);
      return;
    }
    var el = document.querySelector('#teste');   
    el.value += wordsplit[i];    
    triggerEvent(el, 'keyup');
    // triggerEvent(el, 'keydown');
    // triggerEvent(el, 'keypress');
    i++;
  }, 100);
}

function triggerEvent(el, type) {
  if ('createEvent' in document) {        
    var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    e.initEvent(type, false, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(e);        
  }
}

var inputlistener = document.querySelector('#teste');    
inputlistener.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
  console.log('Keypress acionado - Valor: ' + event.target.value);
});

inputlistener.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  console.log('Keydown acionado - Valor: ' + event.target.value);
});

inputlistener.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log('Keyup acionado - Valor: ' + event.target.value);
});

simulate();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="teste" name="teste" />
```

Comment: Na verdade isso funciona mas não ativa os eventos, de keyboard exmplo **keydown**, **keyup** e **key press**.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Excelente era exatamente isto ;D
Obrigado mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```js
var campo = document.querySelector("#texto");
// flag para impedir que o setInterval seja acionado por mais de 1 evento
var flag = true;

campo.addEventListener("change", iniciar);
campo.addEventListener("keyup", iniciar);
campo.addEventListener("keydown", iniciar);
campo.addEventListener("keypress", iniciar);

function iniciar(){

   campo.value = '';
   
   var string = "Olá mundo!"; // texto a ser "digitado"

   if(flag){   
      flag = false;
      var tempo = setInterval(function(){
         var len = campo.value.length;
   
         if(len < string.length){
            campo.value += string.substring(len,len+1);
         }else{
            flag = true;
            clearInterval(tempo);
            console.log("fim!");
         }
      }, 200);
   }
}
```

```html
Pressione alguma tecla do teclado:
<br>
<input autofocus type="text" id="texto">
```

Comment: Isso tembem funciona mas tambem não ativa os eventos, de keyboard exmplo keydown, keyup e key press.

Comment: É eu vi a sua edição da pergunta. Vou verificar...

Comment: Veja se era isso agora.